# Only show post if Author matches Logged in User

Tags: custom-post-types

For some reason this is really vexing me! It should be simple for someone who knows what they are doing? Basically ....

I have setup a sort of 'Profile' based website in Wordpress. Essentially new signed up users become 'Members' (just a derivative of a Subscriber) and purposefully can only see their own profiles. This functionality is dealt with by Ultimate Members plugin.

Within their profiles are links to a custom post called Sessions. Sessions are added by admin and then assigned to the right user with the Author tag. All of this is great - just one problem ......

Once the session is clicked and single-sessions.php loads up - it produces a URL such as mywebsite.com/sessions/joe-blogs-session-1. If I now take that URL & paste it to a new browser whilst changing the username to another user, I can now see their session. This is a big no no!

What I need is some kind of array which acts like:

```
If Author Name = Display name 
{
then show page
}
{

else re-direct to 'sorry' page

}
```

Could anyone tell me how to go about this? I cannot seem to get it to work!

Thanks in advance

Comment: you ask about your code without showing it.... it is very hard to give any useful answer to such questions

Comment: Sorry - as far as I have got I have only managed a function to print both values! I have: <?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'USER DISPLAY NAME:' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
?>

<br />
<br />
AUTHOR : <?php the_author(); ?>

Comment: The above allows me to print the User display name & also a separate function to print the author name. I need a function which checks both & only displays single.php the page if they match ......

Comment: FYI - this seems to get most of the way there .... cheers anyway! <?php
    // check if current user is the post author
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  {
        echo 'You are the seller of this item!';
    }
?>

Comment: @Lee'Yiaggi'Iacovou Please the code to your question, reading the code from the comment is not easy. By the way, what does it have to do with author? The author is the same no matter the browser. Did you mean to check the current user instead?